# Are there examples of using subsquid archive to retrieve a raw block based on a blockhash?

Tags: subsquid, archive, historical

Are there examples of using subsquid archive to retrieve a raw block (Vec) based on a block hash or number? It's very cool that one can query it at the graphql level (E.g. https://app.subsquid.io/aquarium/archives/parallel/subsquid ) but would be nice to be able to ask for the scale encoded block too. (If one's going back in time the normal nodes won't store all the data, and one needs something like subsquid or archive nodes.)